# Connecting to Interactive Brokers TWS via API in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook, interactive-brokers

I am just trying to find ways to get stocks and other data. the code below returns Error 1 504 Not connected

Is it a problem of market hours, of using jupyter, or of some mistakes?

Thank you in advance if you can answer, I am a true coding beginner and I am a bit lost. I followed all the required Global Settings checklist as outlined elsewhere in the website

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper 
from ibapi.contract import Contract

import threading
import time

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType==2 and reqId==1:
        print('The current ask price is: ', price)
        
def run_loop():
    app.run()

app=IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, 10)

#start socket in a thread

api_thread=threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start

time.sleep(1) #sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

#create contract object

apple_contract= Contract()
apple_contract.symbol='AAPL'
apple_contract.secType='STK'
apple_contract.exchange='SMART'
apple_contract.currency='USD'

#request market data

app.reqMktData(1, apple_contract,"", False, False, [])

time.sleep(10) #sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data
app.disconnect()`
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two small issues with the code, the first is likely a typo but the second will cause it to not start the thread and return messages.

```
...
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType==2 and reqId==1:
            print('The current ask price is: ', price)  # 1) Indentation
...

#start socket in a thread
api_thread=threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()   # 2) Parenthesis 

...
```